# Como abrir ventana modal al realizar un login

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-3

Estoy realizando una nueva funcionalidad con mi login y es que requiero que al momento de entrar a su sesión, es decir, después de que entre con su usuario y contraseña, se cargue inmediatamente una ventana modal, adjunto a continuación un pequeño fragmento de código con el cual estoy realizando mi login:

```js
function EntradaLogin(){
    if($('#username').val() != '' && $('#password').val() != '') 
    {                 
        $('.cargando').show(); // Muestra la imagen de cargando
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {
              param: 1,
              username: $('#username').val(),
              password: $('#password').val()
              //tipo: $('#tipo_usuario').val()
            },
            url: "test.php",
           dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.cargando').hide(); // Oculta la imagen de cargando 
                if(data.length){
                    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        if(data[i]['valido'] == 1){
                         $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            async: false,
                            data: {
                              param: 3,
                              username: $('#username').val()
                            },
                            url: "test.php",
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            success: function(data) {
                                if(Parametro ==null){
                                    window.location='test.php';
                                }
                            
                            }
                        });
                            
                        }else{
                            alert("Valdiar usuario o contraseña");
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("Valdiar usuario o contraseña");
                }
           }
        });
    }else{
        alert("Favor de ingresar usuario o contraseña");
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">No. Empleado:</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control"  required/> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control"  required/>        
        </div>
         <button class="btn btn-default" id="login" onclick ="EntradaLogin()">ENTRAR</button>
        </div>
```

La ventana modal que se deseo abrir es la siguiente:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como aclaración estoy usando la versión **3.3.7** de Bootstrap

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes peticiones anidadas y, además, dentro de un ciclo? Se supone que la primera debería devolver el resultado para saber si los datos son correctos o no. Esa lógica complica mucho poder mostrar algo, porque las peticiones dentro del ciclo se van a resolver en momentos diferentes y el orden no siempre será el mismo.

Comment: Es necesario tener las peticiones anidadas de esta manera ya que son varias las validaciones que realizo al realizar el respectivo login

Comment: deberías de estar usando promesas en lugar de peticiones anidadas...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso Sería interesante para una nueva pregunta y lograr cambiar las peticiones anidadas por promesas pero por ahora lo único que me interesa es mostrar una ventana modal después de que se inicie sesión

Comment: es que anidar ajax y ejecutarlo sincrono va en contra del paradigma de ajax... se supone que lo que estas haciendo es asyncrono... la mejor forma de hacer es con promesas...

Comment: segundo lo que quieres hacer es que en el onload de la segunda pagina (después del login te cargue un modal, esto tambien es con promesas) `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {`

Comment: y dentro hago un; inicializar: `$('#myModal').modal({ show: false})` Abrir el modal: `$('#myModal').modal('show');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te explicaba. lo que quieres hacer no esta relacionado a tu login; una vez que tu login se ejecuta y te redirecciona a la nueva pagina, la nueva pagina debe tener implementado lo necesario para que al cargarse se habrá de manera programática/automatica el modal.

Atendiendo a que trabajas con el ya obsoleto *BS 3.3.7* la implementación requiere:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals

**Métodos:**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-methods

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  $('#basicModal').modal({ show: false});
  $('#basicModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**te explico**
para detectar que el contenido de tu pagina (no Ajax) se cargo completamente implementamos esto:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()
```

Para ejecutar la inicializacion de los elementos modal y mostrarlos por pantalla con su efecto ejecutamos esto:

```
$('#basicModal').modal({ show: false});
$('#basicModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, clara y concisa